# Swift - ld:framework not found Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm trying to execute my UITest Alamofire using my xcworkspace project but I can't because I'm facing this issue

[image]

Any ideas guys ?

Comment: What does your Podfile look like?

Comment: 1. Does the Alamofire framework appear in the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" and in "Embedded Binaries" in your app target? 2. Does your app build with success for release?